# Unexpected results with preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I have urls like this:

```
/catalog/kitchen-knives-and-accessories/?clear_cache=Y
```

By using `preg_replace()` I want to make it look like this:

```
section_code=kitchen-knives-and-accessories
```

<sub>Marked everything bold, which I want from the input in my expected result</sub>

Right now I'm using:

```
#^/catalog/([^/]+)#
```

As a regex, but that doesn't give me the expected output when I use it with `preg_replace()`. See: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/dW1

What do I need to change in my regex to get my expected result?

Comment: Look what you get in the first array element. 0 will always contain the full match.

Comment: If you'll follow the link I've provided, you'll see that `preg_match` works fine with this regexp. In first array element I'm getting `/catalog/kitchen-knives-and-accessories` and in the second `kitchen-knives-and-accessories`. That's what I need. But that doesn't work with `preg_replace`

Comment: I don't know why you don't use `preg_match()` then, but you can just grab the entire string and replace it by the first capturing group, e.g. `preg_replace("#^/catalog/([^/]+).*#", "$1", $str)`

Comment: Yeah, that's works. And that's what I've missed. I should make the replacement of the whole string. Thanks! Please post it as an answer and I will confirm that it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `preg_replace()` you have to match the entire string and simply replace it with the capturing group, e.g.

```
$newStr = preg_replace("#^.*/catalog/([^/]+).*#", "section_code=$1", $str);
```